# Is it possible to use a different index page according to the browser?

Tags: html, css

To be more specific, what I am trying to do is to use a different index.php if the user is using Internet Explorer 6 to 8.

In that case I want to index a page which will be prompting the user to download either Firefox or Google Chrome in order to view the site.

Alternatively, I am wondering if it is possible to have a popup window with links to the respective sites of those browsers whenever index is loading, which will check if the user is using IE6 to 8, and if he does, then the site will be deactivated and only the popup window will be active.

I hope I was clear enough with my question.

Thanks in advance, any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do here? I would understand if you were doing something like in html5 and had some epic animations that were just garbage in IE, like my html5 experiments, but for normal sites this is a really bad idea if you're doing it just cause you don't like IE and don't want to support it. Consider spiders, which may appear to be IE or meet whatever requirements you set to identify IE. Then you get indexed with your site reading some download message. That would be bad.

Comment: What I am trying to do is excluding IE user base, I am coding a site in pure html5 and css3 which is really problematic in IE8 and below, there are workaround with various hacks and .htc files but it's a pain in the ass to implement them all, as well as they do not really fix absolutely everything.

Comment: just redirect them to http://abetterbrowser.org/.

Answer (score 2):

A completely separate page is a bit overkill IMO, it should be enough to sniff the browser using some reliable way (e.g. conditional comments), and then loading the warning if the browser is a broken browser.

If you'd like to jump on a bandwagon, there's a bunch of sites that have pre-made banners for this, such as http://www.ie6nomore.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use IE Conditional comments or you can do this with php by checking HTTP_USER_AGENT (not safe, as this is user variable and can be changed to anything).

I suggest you to use this great class from Chris Schuld: http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

p.s. There is also this function in php get_browser() http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is "possible" but perhaps index is not the right approach for this.
You can make use of html `<`!--[if IE]>`link to your IE script here <![endif]-->` which also has operators like `<!--[if lt IE 7]>` for IE less than version 7 and so on. Then have something like jquery or plain javascript handle the rest.

An example would be to make ie.js and have it simply do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(body).html('Please download firefox or chrome to view this site. <a href="http://www.firefox.com">FF</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">Chrome</a>');
});
```

but if you want to go raw PHP you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to switch case and have index.php choose which php file to include based on browser.
Call me crazy, but I'd suggest not doing things this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.htaccess` for this:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  MSIE [0-9]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !MSIE [7-9]
RewriteRule  .*                  /compatible_browsers.html  [L]
```

Hope this helps!